# How to get number of records by matching a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a service model with 3 keywords. And, i have a sales model counting the number of services served to clients. I am trying to make a statistical report and what i want to ask what is the best way to get the number of services sold by service?

For example, I have service A which was sold 10 times, service B which was sold 20 times etc. How do i get these values easily and programmatically?

I do not want to go individually and search the sales model for each instance of service.

What is the best way to go about it?

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :sale_services
  has_many :services, :through => :sale_services

end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sale_services
  has_many :sales, through: :sale_services
end

class SaleService < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sale, optional: true
  belongs_to :service, optional: true
end
```

each service has a price, and each sale has a total_price attribute depending on the number of services sold in that particular sale.

Comment: Can you share the relationship between service and sales, I guess its service has_many sales? But it would be great if you could share the relationship between two models.

Comment: if there is the has_many association between service and sales, then try this: Service.includes(:sales).select("services.name, count(sales.id) as sold_count")

Comment: Yes i am sorry i should add the relationships before! its a many_to_many relationship!

Comment: What is the third model?  I mean how does  it comes into picture, in case of has_many through, would be great if you share all 3 models. Service.where(blah blah).sales.count would be the answer according to known data.

Comment: I actually shared all three models above, its called SaleService ;o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this. Here I am assuming that sales per service is the number of times service is sold.

```
Service.includes(:sales).group("services.name").count("sales")
```

This should give result something like:

```
service_posts = {"service1"=>7, "service2"=>2, "service3"=>0, "service4"=>3, "service5"=>4}
```

if you want to get the prices than you need to do like:

```
service_prices = {}
Service.includes(:sales).each do |service|
  service_prices[service.name] = service_posts[service.name] * service.price
end
```

so service_prices contains the prices for each service.

Comment: yes this is definitely what i want cheers! Could you also help me sum the prices as well? each service has a price and based on what you just did, how can i sum the price * number of instances of that service?

Answer (score 0):

Service.where("your where clause").sales.pluck(:total_price).inject(:+) This will give sum of all sales total_price. Then divide it by base price of sales.